# Location-allocation in ArcGIS Pro: demand point allocated to multiple facilities

Tags: arcgis-pro, network-analysis, location-allocation

I'm working on a location-allocation project in ArcGIS Pro, using the location-allocation network analysis I'm allocating my demand points to new candidate facilities next to already existing ones to see which locations are optimal to be opened (assuming all demand can be fulfilled).

I performed this task regularly, one demand point is assigned to one facility, but I would like to also do this in a way such that a demand point can be assigned to different facilities - such that it shows the percentage of demand fulfilled per facility it is allocated to.

Is there any way to do this in ArcGIS Pro?